# Overloading operator new - misleading output

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, operator-keyword

I'm trying to understand how the placement new/delete works and hence I've written the following program:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Test {};
void * operator new (size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc){
    cout<<"Calling New:"<<endl;
    return new (malloc(size)) Test() ;
}

void operator delete (void *ptr) throw () {
    cout<<"Calling Delete:"<<endl;
    free (ptr) ;
}

int main ()
{
    cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
    Test *ptr = new Test () ;
    delete ptr ;
    return 0;
}
```

For the above code, I'm getting the below output:

```
Calling New:
Calling New:
Calling New:
Calling New:
Calling New:
Calling New:
Calling Delete:
Calling New:
Calling New:
Calling New:
Calling New:
Calling New:
Calling New:
Calling Delete:
Hello
Calling New:
Calling Delete:
```

In the output, it is seen that operator new is called multiple times (even though only one instance of Test is created) and delete is called fewer number of times.

Can anybody please suggest whats wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Global `operator new` should only get and return memory, not call placement new on it.

Comment: Like aschepler said, `return new (malloc(size)) Test() ;` this line is horribly wrong, it should be `return malloc(size);`. Or totally correctly you should echeck for nullptr and throw a bad_alloc

Comment: @aschepler/Mike: While posting the code I had a doubt in the mind that I'm doing something wrong. Anyways, that calls for another question: how do I initialize the object in that location then?

Comment: Seems to be problem with the IDE I'm using. Compiled the same in GCC in UNIX and the output is fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your compilation:

https://ideone.com/uegedB

Here it is called only once.

The Output is:

```
Hello
Calling New:
Calling Delete:
```

Or maybe others things calls it in background.

Answer (score 3):

What is likely happening is that the C++ library uses `operator new` to allocate memory for its internal purposes. For example, writing to `std::cout` could well trigger the allocation of some internal buffers, resulting in calls to the overloaded `operator new`.